# How can I import from Mysql

Tags: database, wordpress

I have two wordpress websites, I want to export all products that I have made in my site 1 and import theme to my site 2, my question is what is products table in Mysql to do this ?

I'll be thanksfull who can help me.

Comment: Are you asking us which table contains the "products" data? Is the table something created by a plugin you've installed? If so then we can't really answer the question without knowing what the plugin is. Even then...can't you just look through your database and find a table which contains the data you're interested in?

Comment: I just want to get export from all my products without using plugins. I don't know the name of the products table in Mysql.

Comment: Ok. Well, how should we know it, do you imagine? We can't see your database. Refer back to my first comment. Look through your database until you find the one which contains the data you want...surely it doesn't have that many tables that you can't spend a few minutes browsing it?

Comment: When all else fails, take a dump of the whole database, open the SQL file in your text editor, look for a product, and scroll up to find out what table it's inserted into.